# How to Populate Checkbox?

Tags: php

I have two fields in my database and they are- name and user_id. I have a page called name.php where I have fives names and checkboxes for each of those names. Now what I want to do is when I visit the page “name.php”, I want names checked which are already inserted in the database. Would you please kindly help me to do this? Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4):

if the value in the db says it is checked you can add the checked attribute to the input element

```
<input type="checkbox" name="thename" checked="checked" />
```

so in your code it will be like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="thename" <?php echo $value == 1 ? 'checked="checked"' : ''?> />
```

this will add the checked attribute if the value is equal to 1

Comment: `checked="checked"` for it to validate as xhtml

Comment: If you use XHTML, you have to write checked="checked" instead.

Comment: "<?php" must be closed with "?>" after the two quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Go over the records of the database, and when generating the chekboxes, see if the name appears in the database. If it does, add `checked="checked"` to the checkbox.

**[Working Example](http://codepad.org/Sjm6COqR)**